# zfs not working after upgrade to 23.04

Tags: zfs, 23.04

I upgraded my 22.10 installation to 23.04, but it won't boot. I had reconfigured /root as zfs a few years ago.
Am I missing a package for zfs to work?

Comment: A simple online (Google, Duckduckgo) search for "grub zfs" will help

Comment: I tried that search, but didn't find anything that would help. The problem seems to be with zsh not connecting to the zsys daemon. I opened a second question, https://askubuntu.com/questions/1465118/couldnt-connect-to-zsys-daemon-after-upgrading-from-22-10-to-23-04, that goes into that problem in more detail.

Comment: When the system boots, it first runs `grub`, which then loads Ubuntu. `grub` by default, can't access ZFS filesystems, and can't find Ubuntu. The search for "`zfs grub`" (`https://duckduckgo.com/?q=zfs+grub`) should let you learn how to configure `grub` for ZFS.The "zsys daemon" is started only after Ubuntu boots, and is not available to `grub`.

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].