# couldn't connect to zsys daemon after upgrading from 22.10 to 23.04

Tags: zfs, 23.04

After upgrading from 22.10 to 23.04, I'm getting the following message:

```
ERROR couldn't connect to zsys daemon: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/zsysd.sock: connect: connection refused"
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.142ubuntu2) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.142ubuntu2) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-20-generic
cryptsetup: ERROR: Couldn't resolve device
    UUID=e50c063b-1ed9-45fc-9626=dcc95195a4ef
W: initramfs-tools configuration sets RESUME=UUID=e50c063b-1ed9-45fc-9626-dcc95195a4ef
W: but no matching swap device is available.
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/nvme0n1p2
I: (UUID=30b393bc-1995-4f6a=9989-3a9e385fbd9d)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
zstd: error 70 : Write error : cannot write block : No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure zstd -q -1 -T0 70
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-6.20-20-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
Error connecting: Could not connect: Connection refused
ERROR couldn't connect to zsys daemon: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/zsysd.sock: connect: connection refused
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
[root /boot]#
```

I have a script for freeing up space on zfs:

```
zfs list -r -t snapshot -o name,used,referenced,creation bpool/BOOT | tail -n +2 | head -n -5 | head -5 | cut -c 35-40 | xargs -n 1 /usr/bin/sudo zsysctl state remove --system
```

But, when I run this script, I get the messages:

```
    level=error msg="couldn't connect to zsys daemon: connection error: desc = "\\"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/zsysd.sock: connect: connection refused\""
    level=error msg="couldn't connect to zsys daemon: connection error: desc = "\\"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/zsysd.sock: connect: connection refused\""
    level=error msg="couldn't connect to zsys daemon: connection error: desc = "\\"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/zsysd.sock: connect: connection refused\""
    level=error msg="couldn't connect to zsys daemon: connection error: desc = "\\"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/zsysd.sock: connect: connection refused\""
    level=error msg="couldn't connect to zsys daemon: connection error: desc = "\\"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/zsysd.sock: connect: connection refused\""
```

I tried restarting zsysd.service:

```
% systemctl restart zsysd.service
Job for zsysd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status zsysd.service" and "journalctl -xeu zsysd.service" for details.
% systemctl status zsysd.service
* zsysd.service - ZSYS daemon service
    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/zsysd.service; static)
    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2023-04-24 22:38:31 PDT; 2min 51s ago
TriggeredBy: * zsysd.socket
    Process: 54726 ExecStart=/sbin/zsysd (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 54726 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 539ms

systemd[1]: Starting zsysd.service - ZSYS daemon service...
zsysd[54726]: level=error msg="Couldn't register grpc server: couldn't create new authorizer: dial unix /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: connect: connection refused"
systemd[1]: zsysd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: zsysd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start zsysd.service - ZSYS daemon service.
```

Any idea of how to fix this?